# VBA - How to run through list of download links (webscraping)

Tags: vba, download

Unfortunately, I am not really familiar with any "components" of HTML code (tags, classes, ids, etc.) and how they differ from each other.
I am trying to have a program run through a list of links, click into each of them and then find any download link on the "clicked-on" page.
My sample URL is "https://c64g.com/games/" and I have managed to run through the list of links and let VBA open each link. However, I cannot let VBA identify how many files are on the page to download as I cannot grab those "elements" from the html.

## Example (selecting the page for "1942"):

```
<h1 class="c64u px16">Free C64 Game Download</h1>
<form action="/games/download/get/12" method="post">
    <button class="btn-link" type="submit">Download 1942.Elite.+2-BAM.zip (31K)</button>
</form>
<form action="/games/download/get/13" method="post">
    <button class="btn-link" type="submit">Download 1942.Elite.+7hpd-REM.zip (38K)</button>
</form>
<form action="/games/download/get/14" method="post">
    <button class="btn-link" type="submit">Download 1942.Elite.CFO.zip (27K)</button>
</form>
<form action="/games/download/get/15" method="post">
    <button class="btn-link" type="submit">Download 1942_v1.Capcom.+2-MHI.zip (25K)</button>
</form>
<form action="/games/download/get/16" method="post">
    <button class="btn-link" type="submit">Download 1942_v2.Capcom.+2p-MHI.zip (37K)</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
```

## VBA code:

```
Sub useClassnames()

Dim ie As Object
Dim internetlink As Object
Dim internetinnerlink As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate ("https://c64g.com/games/")

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "Loading Web page..."
    DoEvents
Loop


Set internetlink = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
i = 0

For Each internetinnerlink In internetlink
'for testing purposes I want only to open the page for "1942", later all links will be run through
    If internetinnerlink.innerText = "1942" Then
        internetinnerlink.Click
        Exit For
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next internetinnerlink

Dim alldownloads As Object
'I have tried any kind of name ("btn-group", "button class", btn-link") and element fetch code (by Id, by name, by tagname, by classname)
Set alldownloads = internetlink(i).getElementsByClassName("btn-group")
MsgBox "alldownloads.Length: " & alldownloads.Length

'ie.Quit

End Sub
```

Any help is truly appreciated, especially explaining why I cannot grab the whole page text (e.g. as a string) and have VBA work through it until it finds the word "btn-link". Of course, then I have to get each link as a separate "element" or "item" (not sure which data format to use then as string wouldn't be the answer). Thank you for explaining how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you referr to the internetlink(i) that it's an array of previous element containing the elements with "a" tag name in the previous page, you should use the IE object that have been loaded with the new page containing the downloads link, get the links from the html body, then do whatever you want with them.

In this example i will show you how to download just one file from that page you asked.

Just read the comment in this code.

The download link are upper the button element in the form action, so we take each btn-link class and with their parent we get the form action (the link to download the file)

Because to download the zip we have to do a POST request, we have to use the SHDocVw.InternetExplorer object Navigate Method to post something that is irrelevant, so i created a test string converted to byte to post it in the request, after navigating a window to download the item should popup in IE.

Give it a try.

```
Sub useClassnames()

Dim ie As Object
Dim internetlink As Object
Dim internetinnerlink As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate ("https://c64g.com/games/")

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "Loading Web page..."
    DoEvents
Loop


Set internetlink = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
i = 0

For Each internetinnerlink In internetlink
    If internetinnerlink.innerText = "1942" Then
        internetinnerlink.Click
        Exit For
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next internetinnerlink


Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "Loading Web page..."
    DoEvents
Loop

Set alldownloads = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn-link")
MsgBox "alldownloads.Length: " & alldownloads.Length
'example with 1 link, you should create an array of them then cycle it, i commented the for each out, you could decomment and use itm to get every btn-link
'For Each itm In alldownloads
    Set tst = alldownloads(0).parentelement 'parent of the button where the form post data is, with the link to the download
    link = tst.Action 'taking the download link
'Next itm


'Now i create and example data to post, we cannot use POST Method in InternetExplorer.Application without posting anything.
FormData = "test"
Dim bFormData() As Byte
ReDim bFormData(Len(FormData) - 1)
bFormData = StrConv(FormData, vbFromUnicode)

'Posting the request to the previous link, now a window with the attempt to download the file should open in IE.
ie.navigate link, Empty, Empty, bFormData

ie.Quit

End Sub
```